# How to find CPU intensive class on Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa

All,
  I have a huge application that processes media files. I get 102% CPU usage when i launch my application and start processing a media file. I would really like a tool that can tell me which class is CPU intensive. That way i can jump to that class and fix it.

Comment: Have you seen [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/AboutTracing/AboutTracing.html)?

Comment: Yes, I did try Activity monitor in Instruments that gives me CPU usage. But it cannot track the exact class that is causing the 100% spike. Other Instrument tools are Memory Usage and Leaks but they are not helpful in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Time Profiler tool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/TimeProfilerInstrument/TimeProfilerInstrument.html) from Instruments.

It will provide you with detailed information with running times for all your functions.

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful. Few questions about the Time Profiler log: If you look at the options you can list the log then there are two of them - 1. Sample List and 2.Call Tree. I understand Call Tree. But when i select "Sample List" then i get a bunch of columns and i don't understand what some of them mean: a. Depth b. CPU (i guess this is the core?) And 3. Hot Frame.